# Which Version of Blackberry JRE is required for Developing BlackBerry OS6

Tags: blackberry, java-me, java

I downloaded the Eclipse plugin for BlackBerry which has the BlackBerry OS 7 runtime by default. I need to target BlackBerry OS 6 and OS 7 devices. Will this work for BlackBerry OS 6 as well, or do I need to change the the JRE?  If I need change the JRE, how do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have already downloaded will be fine for developing for BlackBerry OS 7.  However, to **also** develop for OS 6 devices, you should install the OS 6.0 plugin SDK, too.

Currently, [this blackberry.com page describes the general process you'll need to follow](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/download/eclipse):

1. In Eclipse, select **Help -> Install New Software**.
2. Then click the **Add...** button to add a new software update site, if the BlackBerry site is not already available to **Work with**.
3. Enter the URL for the BlackBerry site ( http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/mac/java for OS X and http://www.blackberry.com/developers/jar/win/java for Windows )
4. If you then select the BlackBerry update site, you should see a category of updates named **BlackBerry Java Plug-In Category**, or something similar.  Expand that, and you should be able to install the 7.1, 7.0, 6.0, or 5.0 SDKs.

[image]

Install all the SDKs whose devices you might want to target as *minimum* versions for your apps.  On Windows, choosing a particular JRE version also gives you at least one simulator that runs that version of BlackBerry smartphone software (Mac OS X SDKs don't support simulators, though).

Once you have a BlackBerry Eclipse project, you will then be able to pick which SDK version you build against.   This will be the *minimum* version that the app will support.

1. Right click the **Project** in the Eclipse **Package Explorer**, and select **Properties**.
2. There, you can see the **Java Build Path** properties, which specify which minimum JRE (OS) version you are targeting.
3. Then, on the **Libraries** tab, you can **Remove** the current JRE (OS) version, and replace it with another one by selecting **Add Library**, then **JRE System Library**.
4. Pick **Alternate JRE** and you should be able to choose from any JRE version whose plugin you installed in the first few steps of these instructions.

That's all!